# Intellij cucumber NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

Here's my gradle setup.

```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:gherkin:5.0.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:2.4.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:2.4.0'
}
```

When I launch cucumber from gradle command everything works fine, but when I run feature from intellij by right clicking I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.IGherkinDialectProvider
```

I've read that this can happen due to gherkin dependency compatibility, so I tried swapping with other gherkin versions, but it didn't help.

Comment: try removing the gherkin and core dependencies. those should be transitive dependencies of cucumber-java